# Should I upgrade to more memory?

Tags: vps, memory

I'm using WHM on a VPS and am trying to work out whether or not I need to upgrade the hardware.

I've currently got 4GB of memory. When I look at the daily process log it seems I have a site averaging around 30% memory usage and another averaging around 15% on the same server. So that's an average of 45% across the day (there are a couple of smaller sites, too), which I suspect means it'll be spiking a lot higher than that? I am experiencing slow loading sites on that server occasionally, hence my interest.

What would be a good % total average memory used for all the sites on a server? As a rule of thumb?

Comment: Taking random measurements by looking into some arbitrary stat at arbitrary times is not helpful in determining cause of "slow loading times". You need to establish a real monitoring environment to help you with this. Also: A VPS means other VPS on the same hardware could slow you down...

Comment: Install some monitoring and tracing system like NewRelic. It'll give you insight into what's using resources, etc.

Comment: Hmm. I know more monitoring and testing will tell me the answer and will probably have to take that route, but I was hoping there might be some ballpark figures out there for your typical web server. I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily - I would start putting up a performance log to see daily highs.

SLow sit eloading can be recompilation due to turning off the site in IIS. I would check that. Again, the performance log will come into an analysis.

50% is not too high - it is borderline. If you expect growth, I would upgrade to 8gb... but still analyze whether this fixes the reasons now.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the advice I was after. It's running Centos.

Answer (score 0):

80% - that's a worry.
70% - nearly a worry
60% - if there's no expected growth then fine.